# Functions that are constant and/or linear on fibers

Tags: differential-geometry

I am trying to understand the following passage that's in a book:

> The set $C^\infty(M)$ of smooth functions on $M$ is in one-to-one correspondence with the set $C^\infty(T^*M)$ of functions that are *constant on fibers* via the map $\alpha \mapsto \pi^*\alpha = \alpha \circ \pi$.

Here, $\pi : T^*M \rightarrow M$ denotes the usual canonical projection $(q,\lambda) \mapsto q$ where $q \in M$ and $\lambda \in T_q^*M$.

**Questions:**

(i) I believe there are various meanings for fibers, but in this case, does it mean $\pi^{-1}\{q\} = \{\lambda \in T_q^*M : \pi(q,\lambda) = q\}$?

(ii) What does it mean for a function, in this setting, to be *linear* and *constant* on fibers?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In (i) you are being redundant. By definition $T_q^*M$ *is* the fiber, because that is $\pi^{-1}(q)$. A function is constant on fibers just as it is constant on any subset; the values are all the same at every point of the fiber. Since $T_q^*M$ is a vector space, you know what it means to have a linear function on it.